# Getting a UIImage from MySQL using PHP and jSON

Tags: php, iphone, mysql, objective-c, json

I'm developing a little news reader that retrieves the info from a website by doing a POST request to a URL. The response is a jSON object with the unread-news.

E.g. the last news on the App has a timeStamp of "2013-03-01". When the user refreshes the table, it POSTS "domain.com/api/api.php?newer-than=2013-03-01". The api.php script goes to the MySQL database and fetches all the news posted after 2013-03-01 and prints them json_encoded. This is

```
// do something to get the data in an array
echo $array_of_fetched_data;
```

for example the response would be `[{"title": "new app is coming to the market", "text": "lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...", image: XXX}]`

the App then gets the response and parses it, obtaining an `NSDictionary` and adds it to a Core Data db.

```
 NSDictionary* obtainedNews = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
```

My question is: How can I add an image to the MySQL database, store it, pass it using jSON trough a POST HTTP Request and then interpret it as an UIImage.

It's clear that to store an UIImage in CoreData, they must be transform into/from NSData. How can I pass the NSData back and forth to a MySQL db using php and jSON? How should I upload the image to the db? (Serialized, as a BLOB, etc)

Answer (score 2):

While you could base64 encode your images and stick that into your output json...

What I did when I was in your situation was to include a url link to that image instead in the json output and then fetching the data:

```
NSString *image = @"http://dphi.ca/files/2010/01/flower.png";
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:image] options:NSDataReadingUncached error:&error];
// write the data down somewhere as to not fetch it all the time
UIImage *uimage = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

Doing it this way will allow you to simply treat the image as a normal image when uploading, storing and downloading it.